# Using Spring's @Scheduled annotation with a specific executor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

How do I tell my Spring scheduled method to run using a specific executor?

For example, this is one of my spring scheduler method,

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
public void scheduleJobs(){
    doThese();
}
```

And here are the 2 executors defined in my Java config:

```
@Bean
public Executor taskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler t = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    t.setPoolSize(2);
    t.setThreadNamePrefix("taskScheduler - ");
    t.initialize();
    return t;
}

@Bean
public Executor newTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler t = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    t.setPoolSize(2);
    t.setThreadNamePrefix("newTaskScheduler - ");
    t.initialize();
    return t;
}
```

When the scheduled method is running I can see it is using `taskScheduler` executor. How to tell it to run using `newTaskScheduler` executor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Javadoc of `@EnableScheduling`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) is pretty exhaustive in that area.

You need to implement a `SchedulingConfigurer` to fine-tune which `Executor` needs to be used.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can not find anything in the docs which instructs how `@Scheduled` method can be run on separate executor. I'm afraid it is not possible (yet) as @Gaurav pointed out

Comment: my answer does not answer your question it seems. If you want to be able to fine tune the executor _per scheduled method_ it isn't possible at the moment but there is [an issue in our tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14218). My answer is about customizing _the_ executor that all scheduled methods use.

Comment: The issue in the comment above was closed as a duplicate. The active and open ticket is now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20818

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20818 was released as part of spring 6.1

Answer (score 11):

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

 @Override
 public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
  taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());
 }

 @Bean
 public Executor taskScheduler() {
  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler t = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
  t.setPoolSize(2);
  t.setThreadNamePrefix("taskScheduler - ");
  t.initialize();
  return t;
 }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

Executor qualification with @Scheduled is not supported yet.

Refer -
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14218

Comment: That issue became closed as a duplicate. The open ticket is now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20818