# Can you specify different Executors for Scheduled tasks in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, job-scheduling

Spring uses the same executor for all `@Scheduled` tasks.  Which, by default, has 1 thread but you can create a custom one with more.

**Situation**: I have 2 types of jobs I want to schedule:

1. long running background jobs: don't necessarily need to start right on time, don't want them to possibly all run at the same time and definitely don't want more than one of each job running at once (solution: use fixed delay with limited thread pool)
2. frequent, short running jobs that need to run when scheduled. (solution: use fixed rate with `@Async`)

**Problem**: the slow jobs on limited pool directly opposes running others with `@Async`
Ideally, I would have 2 separate executors I could assign doing something like

`@Scheduled(delayedRate=600000, executor="longRunningExecutor")` and `@Scheduled(fixedRate=5000, executor="rightNowExecutor")`

but I can't find anything supporting something like this.

How can I ensure the long-running jobs don't hog the thread pool and block the right-now ones?

Comment: Hi, your question is a possible duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018041/use-spring-scheduled-with-a-specific-executor

Comment: Duplicate adjacent? I saw that question, but they accepted an answer for selecting which executor all scheduled tasks run on. I'm looking for selecting for each specific task.  However, I did overlook one of the other answers starting it's not supported but may be in the future. So, thanks for correcting me back to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use spring @scheduled with a specific executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018041/use-spring-scheduled-with-a-specific-executor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the answer is "they're working on it" https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20818

Comment: this was released as part of spring 6.1